# Is it portable to self move a std::string?

Tags: c++, c++20

```
std::string s = "y";
s = "x" + std::move(s) + "x";
Send(std::move(s));
```

Microsoft STL implementation checks for this, but is it mandated by the standard?

It looks more clean than insert + append or two variables approach.

Note: I know I can do `Send(std::move("x" + std::move(s) + "x"))`, but real code is not so simple.

Comment: Is the question about the `move` in the second line? If so, the third line isn't relevant.

Comment: In `"x" + std::move(s) + "x"`, what is the purpose of that `std::move`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude first operator+ will create copy of s, because it is lvalue

Comment: Premature optimization. You're very likely not having anything to `std::move` in the first place due to Small String Optimization. Optimize for readability unless you have hard evidence that performance is an issue. (I'd also argue that this does not "look more clean" in any way or form.)

Comment: "*It looks more clean than insert + append or two variables approach.*" No, it doesn't. The fact that you have to think *at all* about whether this code is legit already tells you that it's not clean. You don't have to think about the legitimacy of clean code.

Comment: *I know I can do Send(`std::move("x" + std::move(s) + "x")`)*  Both uses of `std::move` here are a premature pessimizations and unnecessary since the interim results are a temporaries.

Comment: @Eljay I agree on outer `move`, but inner `move` will not reuse buffer of `s` and will allocate new one

Comment: Even with the inner move, it will not reuse the buffer of `s` and will allocate a new one.  Left to right associativity of binary `operator+`.

Comment: @Eljay with `move` first call is `operator+(const char*, string&&)` instead of `operator+(const char*, const string&)`

Comment: I stand corrected, I see there is an optimization for that situation.  I am a bit surprised that `operator+(string&&, string&&)` is not better optimized with my compiler (it always selects the lhs, rather than which one has bigger capacity).

Comment: @Eljay It's your opportunity to make the world better. See how it can be implemented here.  
https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/dc888f7d9fb7a4db8d3441f9e9bac2e0c6ecc4db/stl/inc/xstring#L4784  
https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/dc888f7d9fb7a4db8d3441f9e9bac2e0c6ecc4db/stl/inc/xstring#L2694

Comment: That's impressive and unexpected!  Microsoft sure has changed a lot since I worked there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no self-move here. A self-move is something like this:

```
s = std::move(s);
```

which means

```
s.operator=(std::move(s));
```

In other words, when `operator=` is called, `this` points to the same string as the argument.

In your code, `"x" + std::move(s)` will be evaluated first, which returns a `std::string` prvalue. In other words, *not* a reference to `s`, although it's possible that the concatenation might "steal" the buffer from `s`. Then the second `+` is evaluated, and another prvalue is returned. Finally, `operator=` is called. At this point, the prvalue on the right-hand side has to be materialized, because it's bound to the rvalue reference argument of `operator=`. So all we have is `s` being assigned from a temporary object, which *might* have stolen `s`'s buffer. But no matter: `s` is an object of a standard library type, which means that it is in a "valid but unspecified state". Since `s` is in a valid state, and is not the same object as the RHS, there is no problem.

Comment: I looking at implementation and see this: `basic_string<...> operator+(
    const _Elem* const _Left, basic_string<...>&& _Right) {
    return _STD move(_Right.insert(0, _Left));
}` which just returns rvalue reference to `s`, so in `basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& _Right)` we have `this == &s`

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic `operator+` does not return an rvalue reference to its argument. It returns a prvalue that, in the case of the specific implementation you are looking at, is initialized from its rvalue reference argument. Notice that the return type is not rvalue reference.

Comment: Ohh, I see now.

Comment: I would say that for any type with a non-trivial identity operation self-move should give the same result as self-assignment. For example, it would be very strange if `s = std::move(s) + ""` and `s = std::move(s)` mean different things. `std::vector` as far I know doesn't have a natural identity operation, so in that case `v = std::move(v)` could be anything, in fact, I think it can mean anything depending on the implementation.

Comment: @alfC `v = std::move(v);` and `v=v;` are no-op. It is one of basics to ensure to self assignment doesn't cause any issues. In general, it isn't required to be no-op but I am yet to find a case where it isn't (unless one does some side effects for whatever reasons).

Comment: @alfC @ALX23z `move` should transit object into moved-out state, so in general case self-move more like calling `reset()` or `clear()`.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic, mmm, yes, it doesn't completely contradict what I said. Perhaps this is a good reason for `std::string` to not have a `.clear()` method. But the point is well taken. I guess it is controversial.

Comment: @ALX23z, `v = std::move(v)` clears the vector for some (most?) implementations. I think it is the natural result when you take into account "performance" (minimize the number of operations and checks). And it is not what "`int`s do"©

Comment: There is a counterpart to this dilemma, which is "what should unary operator+ return when it exists?". My conclusion so far is that it should always return a copy even if it can take advantage of move. This way s = +std::move(s) is always well defined even if it is not optimal for a particular case. Tangentially, also "what should `std::identity` return?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic `std::move` is merely a cast, hence what `v = std::move(v)` does depends all on the `=`

Comment: The post condition of the *move* assignment is that the object is left in a *valid but unspecified* state for most standard C++ library objects.  Some classes have additional guarantees.  Self-move-assignment results in an object in a *valid but unspecified* state; not a no-op.  (*valid but unspecified* is suitable for destruction or re-assignment or for any member functions without preconditions.  Otherwise, a kissing cousin of **undefined behavior**.)

Comment: @Eljay, I think we are all in the same page here. My particular point is that, in the context of other operations, then the behavior should be more specific (more specified). *if* the type has some "algebra" associated, then, for consistency, self-move-assignment should behave specifically. `std::vector` doesn't have any well defined algebra, so there is no guideline for self-assignment. (The only reference point is clear() perhaps). std::string does have an algebra, although a shaky one, so it could be used as guideline to what self assignment should do.

Comment: @alfC • Agreed.  Howard Hinnant (here on Stack Overflow) had pointed out that a developer's *own* classes can have whatever post-conditions they want for a moved-from object.  The standard C++ libraries are the ones with the *valid but unspecified* idiom.  My own code tends to follow that as well, with a couple extra debug-build-only boogers to detect if I mess up.